# Service 'wp' depends on service 'wpdb:mysql' which is undefined

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to build and run the following `yml` file using `docker-compose up -d` and I am getting the following error:

`Service 'wp' depends on service 'wpdb:mysql' which is undefined.`

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
   services:
       wpdp:
           image: mariadb
           ports:
               - "8081:3306"
           environment:
               MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root_password"
               MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
               MYSQL_USER: "db_user"
               MYSQL_PASSWORD: "db_password"
      wp:
          image: wordpress
          volumes:
              - ./:/var/www/html
          ports:
              - "8080:80"
          depends_on:
              - wpdb:mysql
          links:
              - wpdb:mysql
          environment:
              WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "wp_user"
              WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "wp_password"
              WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "db_name"
```

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@tatemz/local-wordpress-development-with-docker-3-easy-steps-a7c375366b9).

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution

Comment: try to replace wpdp: by wpdb: in services

Comment: Lol.... Totally missed it. Thanks a lot and happy new year!

Comment: That made me look at my keyboard and decided I needed a Zantac sandwich and Valium-infused tears of a virgin unicorn.